# why is struct not accepting a string as an input

Tags: python, struct

i got an issue with structs not packing a string

i currently create a random 20 byte long string and when i try to pack this using structs in 20 octets by the code below

```
    payload = struct.pack("H" * 20, *rendezvous_cookie)

   rendezvous_cookie calculated by  os.urandom(20)
```

i get the error struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer

is there any quick easy way of encoding the string so it can be packed this way?

Thanks

Edit managed to fix it by doing :

```
payload = struct.pack('!20s', rendezvous_cookie)
```

this way it takes the input as a string fine and is still of 20 octets

Comment: Why do you want to feed this through `struct`, anyway? If you want a string, you already have it. (If you want ints, you want `unpack`.)

Comment: i want to pack the data from the cookie into a payload of 20 octets containing the information as i then want to send this data in a packet

Comment: It's already a payload of 20 octets. Your final struct.pack is essentially a NOP. Prove it to yourself: `foo = os.urandom(20); bar = struct.pack('!20s', foo); foo == bar`

Comment: Also realize that struct's 'H' yields an unsigned short, not an octet.

Answer (score 1):

`os.urandom(n)` returns a random `str` of length `n`.

If you want to make a list of integers out of it, use:

```
[ord(b) for b in os.urandom(n)]
```

You can feed that as arguments to `struct.pack`.

Note, however, that `os.urandom(n)` **already returns a serialized list of bytes**. You may be able to use that directly. Using `struct.pack("H", ...)` makes each number occupy two bytes (one of which will hold no data).